# How to import a python module accessible via an url

Tags: python, sharepoint, import

My company uses some kind of version-control archival tool (Microsoft Windows), and I would like to make direct imports from it. But I can't find a way to do that.

Here's what I tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r"http://some_path_copied_and_pasted/05.Autres%20Outils/Regen_Engine")
>>> sys.path
['C:\\Python26\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python26\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages', 'http://some_path_copied_and_pasted/05.Autres%20Outils/Regen_Engine']
>>> import regen_engine as r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import regen_engine as r
ImportError: No module named regen_engine
```

I tried by replacing the "%20" of the URL with " " (spaces), but the result is the same. I also tried by using the `imp` module, but no better.

So here are my questions:

1. is it possible to make an import from an URL?
2. if yes, how can I make it happen?

Maybe a solution could be to access this file with some other, hidden path of Sharepoint, so a tag for it would be appropriate.

Comment: Never try it but take a look on the xhtmlhook: http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/xhtmlhook/

Comment: From what I understood, this seems more related to xhtml for documentation purpose. I mean, Sharepoint is visible as a web portal, but I still can find my python script by direct access in a web browser with complete URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib
def urlimport(x):
    exec urllib.urlopen(x) in globals()
```

This is the wrong way to do this, you should never use this in production code, its just a proof of concept.

Comment: Following your example, I started to test this just by reading the script. But now I have some connexion problem: `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>`. So I guess I'll have to check this first, and I bet it's related to this not-so-cool Sharepoint portal, maybe some kind of access-rights policy. Not so simple as it seemed at first glance...

Comment: That's obvious, hence my comment "I'll have to check". From your first answer, I understood that Python can import from URL (even if a bit tricky); now my work will be to understand how to handle this sharepoint server. So thanks for the piece of evidence.

Comment: Doing it like that I got an error: "TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object". I changed it slightly to 
import urllib;
filepath = urllib.urlretrieve(url)[0];
with open(filepath) as f:
    exec f in globals();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def dynamic_import_by_uri(file)
    file = os.path.abspath(file)
    exec open(file, 'rb') in globals()
```

It works but it is unsafe for production version...